# Java plugin 7u40 can't load an applet just after leaving a page with another applet

Tags: java, security, plugins, applet

### Symptoms

I have a web application running on Tomcat.
Some web pages contain applet, packed and signed with CA certificate and requested "permissions: all-permissions" in the manifest.

I have the latest **JRE 7u40** on the client side.
When I browse a page with the applet it loads successfully without security or other warnings.
When I leave this page and return back to this page in short time (less then 60 seconds) the applet can't be loaded.
If I leave the page, then wait until java.exe and jp2launcher.exe exit, and then return back to the page, the applet loads successfully again.

This behaviour changed from **JRE 7u25** where the applet loaded successfully in all cases.
This issue is reproducible on **Windows 7 with IE 8** and on Windows 7 with the latest Chrome 30.0.x.x.
I can't reproduce it On Windows 8 with IE 10.

### Workaround

The only workaround that I know is System.exit() in applet.destroy() with separate_jvm applet parameter. But I think that this is too brute.
**Do you know any other workarounds?**

### Technical info

First, I turn on tracing in Java Control Panel.
Second, I turn on browser-jvm debugging
JPI_PLUGIN2_DEBUG=1
JPI_PLUGIN2_VERBOSE=1

When I leave the page with the applet, I see the following in the applet console, so I think that applet is stop and destroyed.

> ```
> PluginMain: processing GetAppletMessage
> PluginMain: processing JavaObjectOpMessage
> LiveConnectSupport: HAS_FIELD_OR_METHOD "rf"
> network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.40
> network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.25
> LiveConnectSupport: HAS_FIELD_OR_METHOD "rf": returning result false
> PluginMain: processing JavaObjectOpMessage
> LiveConnectSupport: HAS_FIELD_OR_METHOD "onremove"
> network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.40
> network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.25
> LiveConnectSupport: HAS_FIELD_OR_METHOD "onremove": returning result false
> PluginMain: processing StopAppletMessage, applet ID 1
> basic: Starting applet teardown
> basic: Finished applet teardown
> basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1c24701
> basic: PluginMain.unregisterApplet: 1 from mananger sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2Manager@6f403e
> Applet2Manager executing destroyTGAndAC() for entry http://host:80/AppName/applet/,myapplet.jar
> ```

When I revisit the page in short time (less than 60 seconds), I see the following error in the debug command window associated with the browser process.

> Attempting to start applet
>   Exception in thread "Thread-0"
>   java.lang.InternalError: Should not find a running JVM instance but no
>   matching JRE platform
>           at sun.plugin2.main.server.JVMManager.getBestJVMInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.plugin2.main.server.JVMManager.getOrCreateBestJVMInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.plugin2.main.server.JVMManager.startAppletImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.plugin2.main.server.JVMManager.startApplet(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.plugin2.main.server.JVMManager.startApplet(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.plugin2.main.server.IExplorerPlugin.maybeStartApplet(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.plugin2.main.server.IExplorerPlugin.access$200(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.plugin2.main.server.IExplorerPlugin$BackgroundStarter$1.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.plugin2.main.server.IExplorerPlugin$1.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: I could immediately see an existing bug, but the public bug database appears to searchable from http://bugs.sun.com/ . And you can report a bug at http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/ .

Comment: Ok, I've submitted a bug to bugs.sun.com. Thanks for advice. I've also found, that separate_jvm=true is quite enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that

```
<param name="separate_jvm" value="true"/>
```

is quite enough.